# Spatial Analysis: use of buffer function inside GeoDjango's LineString model

Tags: python, spatial-analyst, buffer, linestring, geodjango

I'm trying to make a buffer around a line. I've a model with a LineString field and I would to use the buffer function [like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.buffer) to make my buffer. The aim of this is render the buffer on a webmap using MapBox.

I have this simple model:

```
class LinesSource(models.Model):
    geom = models.LineStringField()

def __int__(self):
    return self.pk  

@property
def buffer(self):
    """pseudo-code"""
    distance = 200 ##I need the distance in meters and my model SRID is in degree but this is not a problem
    mybuffer = geom.buffer(width=distance, quadsegs=8) ##something like GEOSGeometry.buffer(width, quadsegs=8)
    return mybuffer
```

My problem is that is not clear to me how I can change the pseudo-code to real code because for me is not clear how I can use the spatial analysis function inside GeoDjango.

Someone can made a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is add a polygon field and use the save method to update the polygon field when a line is drawn on the linestring field. The buffer function must be something like this: `self.geom.buffer(distance, quadsegs=8)`